# Holding state in zsh completions

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I want to write zsh completions for a program with the following calling convention:

```
program [generaloptions] operation [operationoptions]
```

where `operation` is one of `--install`, `--upgrade`...

What I have so far, are the general options and the operation options. My code looks something like this:

```
local generaloptions; generaloptions=(...)
local installoptions; installoptions=(...)
local upgradeoptions; upgradeoptions=(...)

case "$state" in
  (install)
    _arguments -s \
      "$installoptions[@]" \
      && ret=0
  (upgrade)
    _arguments -s \
      "$upgradeoption[@]" \
      && ret=0
  *)
    _arguments -s \
      "$generaloptions[@]" \
      '--install[...]: :->install' \
      '--upgrade[...]: :->upgrade' \
      && ret=0
```

The problem is, after I type the operation and the first operation option, the state gets reset to the `*)` case.

#### Example

```
$ program --install --installoption --<tab>
list of general options
```

How can I set the next state to be the same as the old? Which command has similar calling conventions, so I can look at the code of the completion for this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the operations start with a `--`, so it is harder to find them in the arguments. In git for example all subcommands are only a word without dashes. So git solves this problem something like this:

1. Find the first argument without dashes because this must be the subcommand
2. Dispatch based on the subcommand to the commandline arguments for that subcommand.

So git dispatches in **every** call to the completion function (this was what I meant with "holding the state").

The way I solved this problem was by looking through many completion functions and finding a command that had a similar calling convention. The command that I found the most useful is `pacman`. Here is what I extracted from that:

```
# This somehow disassembles the commandline options
args=( ${${${(M)words:#-*}#-}:#-*}
case $args in
  *i)
    _arguments -s \
      ${installoptions} \
      '(-i[...]' \
      && ret=0
    ;;
  *u)
    _arguments -s \
      ${upgradeoption} \
      '-u[...]' \
      && ret=0
    ;;
  *)
    case ${(M)words:#--*} in
      *--install*)
        _arguments -s \
          ${installoptions} \
          '--install[...]' \
          && ret=0
      ;;
      *--upgrade*)
        _arguments -s \
          ${upgradeoption} \
          '--upgrade[...]' \
          && ret=0
      ;;
      *)
        _arguments -s \
          {generaloptions} \
          && ret=0
      ;;
    esac
 esac
```

I know, there is a lot of dublication, but I think you get the point. Also notice, I moved the `--install` and `--upgrade` options from the general case to the operation case. If you don't do that, you loose the argument if you want complete after `--install` or `--upgrade`